# How to access a sequence of all elements in Array of CGPoints in Swift

Tags: arrays, macos, swift2

I have an array named Trapezoid containing CGPoints from 0 to n. How to get all the elements of this array and feed them to For-In loop?

In my code I have an error at first line: Cannot convert value of type '[Trapezoid].Type' (aka 'Array<[Trapezoid]>.Type') to specified type '[CGPoint]'.

```
let printedArray: [CGPoint] = [Trapezoid]

for (index, calculatedPoint) in printedArray.enumerate() {

    let pointElement = NSXMLElement(name: "point")
    let xx = calculatedPoint.x
    let yy = calculatedPoint.y

    pointElement.attributes = [
        xmlAttributeWithName("id", value: "\(index)"),
        xmlAttributeWithName("x", value: "\(xx)"),
        xmlAttributeWithName("y", value: "\(yy)") ]
    }
```

//Declaration of Trapezoid

```
enum Trapezoid {

   case vertexOne(point: CGPoint)
   case vertexTwo(point: CGPoint)
   case vertexThree(point: CGPoint)
   case vertexFour(point: CGPoint)

func controlPointCoordinates() -> [CGPoint] {

    switch self {

        case .vertexOne(let point): return [point]
        case .vertexTwo(let point): return [point]
        case .vertexThree(let point): return [point]
        case .vertexFour(let point): return [point]
    }
}


func segmentedPath(path: CGMutablePath) {

    switch self {

        case .vertexOne(let point): CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, point.x, point.y)
        case .vertexTwo(let point): CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, point.x, point.y)
        case .vertexThree(let point): CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, point.x, point.y)
        case .vertexFour(let point): CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, point.x, point.y)

        CGPathCloseSubpath(path)
        NSColor.darkGrayColor().setStroke()
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Show your declaration of Trapezoid.

Comment: Error: Type 'Trapezoid' has no member 'map'.

Comment: Correct, `Trapezoid` doesn't. Your array of `Trapezoid` (i.e. `Array<Trapezoid>` or `[Trapezoid]`) does.

Comment: Now Xcode says: for xx and yy it has no members x and y

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice that you've curiously defined your `enum` to represent a single point, but `controlPointCoordinates` always returns an array with exactly only one point (which makes no sense; why would you return an array when this enum represents only one point?). So, with your existing `enum` definition, you'd do `let printedArray = someArrayOfTrapezoids.map { return $0.controlPointCoordinates()[0] }` or `let printedArray = someArrayOfTrapezoids.flatMap { $0.controlPointCoordinates() }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you have some array that is an array of `Trapezoid` that you want to convert to an array of `CGPoint`?

```
var someArrayOfTrapezoids = [Trapezoid]()
// add some Trapezoid values
```

Given that `controlPointCoordinates` returns an array with a single `CGPoint`, you could convert that to an array of `CGPoint` with either:

```
let printedArray = someArrayOfTrapezoids.map { $0.controlPointCoordinates()[0] }
```

or

```
let printedArray = someArrayOfTrapezoids.flatMap { $0.controlPointCoordinates() }
```

---

There is some dissonance here, though, given that a type called `Trapezoid` sounds like it should be a full trapezoid, but it's only one coordinate of a trapezoid. I'd either redefine it to be a single point, e.g.

```
enum TrapezoidPoint {

    case vertexOne(point: CGPoint)
    case vertexTwo(point: CGPoint)
    case vertexThree(point: CGPoint)
    case vertexFour(point: CGPoint)

    func controlPointCoordinate() -> CGPoint {      // note, not [CGPoint], and not `controlPointCoordinates`, but rather `controlPointCoordinate`
        switch self {
        case .vertexOne(let point): return point
        case .vertexTwo(let point): return point
        case .vertexThree(let point): return point
        case .vertexFour(let point): return point
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

In which case you'd do:

```
let printedArray = arrayOfTrapezoidPoints.map { $0.controlPointCoordinate() } // the `[0]` is no longer needed
```

Or define it to be all four points:

```
struct Trapezoid {

    let vertexOne: CGPoint
    let vertexTwo: CGPoint
    let vertexThree: CGPoint
    let vertexFour: CGPoint

    func controlPointCoordinates() -> [CGPoint] {
        return [vertexOne, vertexTwo, vertexThree, vertexFour]
    }
    ...
}
```

And then you could do:

```
let printedArray = someSingleTrapezoidWithFourPoints.controlPointCoordinates()
```

Comment: Xcode writes: Use of instance member 'controlPointCoordinates' on type 'Trapezoid'....

Comment: So, double check the spelling of your `controlPointCoordinates` method on your `Trapezoid` `enum`. Make sure to include the `()`, too: `let printedArray = someArrayOfTrapezoids.map { $0.controlPointCoordinates()[0] }`.

Comment: It works. Thanx a lot) 

I assigned
var totalArray: [Trapezoid] = []

Answer (score 1):

A Trapezoid in no sense has multiple CGPoints. It contains *one* CGPoint, which your `controlPointCoordinates` wraps up in an array (for no apparent reason).

Given an array of Trapezoid, you can map it to an array *of arrays* of CGPoint by mapping through its `controlPointCoordinates`:

```
let printedArray: [[CGPoint]] = myTrapezoidArray.map {$0.controlPointCoordinates()}
```

You could then *flatten* the array of arrays of CGPoint to get an array of CGPoint:

```
let realPrintedArray = printedArray.flatten()
```

You can then cycle through the flattened array with `for...in` and get a CGPoint on each iteration.

But really, wouldn't it be simpler if `controlPointCoordinates` returned a CGPoint instead of an array?

Answer (score -3):

Without knowing how you have set up Trapezoid or CGPoint, it is difficult to answer your question fully. However, if Trapezoid is an array of CGPoints, you could try:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Trapezoid.length(); i++){
    CGPoint[i] = Trapezoid[i]; 
}
```

Or put in whatever you need to do in order to convert between the two types.